# How to detect the form name when mouse is position on any SDI form

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

i was looking for trick to get the form name when mouse is place on it. suppose i have one mdi form and many sdi form like form1,form2,form3 and all sdi form are opened. suppose i have one timer running on form1 and which will run periodically. i want to show the form name on form1's label from the timer tick event  when mouse is positioned on any SDI form window.

this way i try to do it. here is the code

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var handle = WindowFromPoint(Cursor.Position);
    if (handle != IntPtr.Zero) {
        var ctl = Control.FromHandle(handle);
        if (ctl != null) {
            label1.Text = ctl.Name;
            return;
        }
    }
    label1.Text = "None";
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point pos);
```

the above code run perfectly but there is some glitch. when i place my mouse on MDI form or on Form1 then form name is showing on form1 but when i place the mouse on Form2 or Form2 then their name is not showing. i am not being able to understand what is the problem in this code. please guide me to fix it.

Comment: What do you mean by "mouse is on it"? Do you mean hovering over it, without necessarily activating the form, or that the form is the active form among the children, i.e. the one that has focus?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the control, I think you just need to use the `FindForm()` function:

```
var ctl = Control.FromHandle(handle);
if (ctl != null) {
  var form = ctrl.FindForm();
  if (form != null) {
    label1.Text = form.Name;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Thomas It will return the form instance for the parent of the control.  See [Control.FindForm Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.findform.aspx).  It sounded like what you are trying to do with your code.  It's not clear if you want the "name" of the form, or the "text" (title) of the form.  For the title, replace `form.Name` with `form.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason Form2's name isn't showing up is that the instance of Form2 that you have created does not have a name.  In order to demonstrate this, take a look at the following code block, situated in a Program.cs file:

```
MDIParent mdi = new MDIParent();
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
frm1.MdiParent = mdi;
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.MdiParent = mdi;
frm1.Show();
frm2.Show();
Application.Run(mdi);
```

If you add a breakpoint, you will see that Form2's name is blank.  But wait, there's more!

If you add a control, any control, to Form 2, it **will** have a name when you create it.  It looks like the naming system does not feel the need to assign the form control a name until multiple controls are present, which it does during its `InitializeComponent` call.  You can take a look at this code.  Here is the code generated for "Form3" with no controls:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.Text = "Form3";
}
```

And here is the same form after a label has been added:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // label1
    // 
    this.label1.AutoSize = true;
    this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
    this.label1.Name = "label1";
    this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
    this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.label1.Text = "label1";
    // 
    // Form3
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
    this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
    this.Name = "Form3";
    this.Text = "Form3";
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.PerformLayout();

}
```

As you can see, a name is only assigned to the form if other controls are present.  As for why this is the case, you would probably have to ask the person who wrote the auto-generation code for that answer.